# Java - write string to file line by line vs one-liner / cannot convert String to String[]

Tags: java, string

Relatively new to programming. I want to read a URL, modify the text string, then write it to a line-separated csv textfile.

The read & modify parts run. Also, outputting the string to terminal (using Eclipse) looks fine (csv, line by line), like this;

```
data_a,data_b,data_c,...
data_a1,data_b1,datac1...
data_a2,data_b2,datac2...
.
.
.
```

But I'm unable to write the same string to file - it just becomes a one-liner (see my below for-loops, attempts no. 1 & 2);

```
data_a,data_b,data_c,data_a1,data_b1,datac1,data_a2,data_b2,datac2...
```

I guess I'm looking for a way to, in the FileWriter or BufferedWriter loops, convert the string finalDataA to array string (i.e. include the string suffix "[0]") but I have not yet found such an approach that would not give errors of the type "Cannot convert String to String[]". Any suggestions?

```
    String data = "";
    String dataHelper = "";
    try {
        URL myURL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
        if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == URLStatus.HTTP_OK.getStatusCode()) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myConnection.getInputStream()));

            while ((data = in.readLine()) != null) {
                     dataHelper = dataHelper + "\n" + data;
            }
            in.close();

            String trimmedData = dataHelper.trim().replaceAll(" +", ",");
            String parts[] = trimmedData.split(Pattern.quote(")"));// ,1.,");
            String dataA = parts[1];
            String finalDataA[] = dataA.split("</PRE>");
            // parts 2&3 removed in this example

            // Console output for testing purpose - This prints out many many lines of csv-data
            System.out.println(finalDataA[0]);
            //This returns the value 1
            System.out.println(finalDataA.length);

            // Attempt no. 1 to write to file - writes a oneliner
            for(int i = 0; i < finalDataA.length; i++) {
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathA, true))) {
                    String s;
                    s = finalDataA[i];
                    bw.write(s);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                }
            }

            // Attempt no. 2 to write to file - writes a oneliner
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(pathA);
            for (int i = 0; i < finalDataA.length; i++) {
              fw.write(finalDataA[i] + "\n");
            }
            fw.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" +e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code comments, `finalDataA` has one element, so the for-loop will be executed only once. Try splitting `finalDataA[0]` into rows.
Something like this:

```
    String endOfLineToken = "..."; //your variant
    String[] lines = finalDataA[0].split(endOfLineToken)
    BufferdWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathA, true));
    try 
    {
       for (String line: lines)
       {
           bw.write(line);
           bw.write(endOfLineToken);//to put back line endings
           bw.newLine();
           bw.flush();
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: This writes two line terminators per line. You don't need both `write(endOfLineToken)` *and* `newLine()`. `newLine()` alone is sufficient.

Comment: @EJP The name endOfLineToken may be confusing, but it should be obvious from usage, that  isn't necessary a "\n" or CR or whatever. It is supposed to delimit rows in unparsed data.

Answer (score 2):

Create the `BufferedWriter` and the `FileWriter` ahead of the for loop, not every time around it.